# regex pattern for numeric values in aws s3 bucket policy

Tags: regex, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bucket

how to build regex pattern in aws s3 bucket policy to allow only specific files with names and extensions copied to s3 bucket.
ex: DGCSCons_**6193_20150422**.dat_AEL.dat.bz2
in the above file name i want to build regex for numeric characters along with specifying _. how to do this?

Comment: What language do you use?

Comment: This regex will split the parts of those filenames into capture groups. `(\w+)_((\d{4})_(\d{8}))((?:\.\w+)+)` . Then in your code you can check on the content of those groups wether to allow them or not.

Comment: @Andreas in AWS s3 bucket policy. it is json

Comment: @LukStorms i tried the pattern provided but AWS throwing error while validating json file

Comment: Don't know about AWS or what regex flavor it uses.  If it has a problem with the regex then perhaps it requires to backslash every backslash? It's something you also see in javascript. For example `\d+` in a pattern in a string variable would have to written as `"\\d+"`.

Answer (score 4):

Resource ARNs in policies only support wildcards, not regexes.

> You can use wildcards as part of the resource ARN. You can use wildcard characters (* and ?) within any ARN segment (the parts separated by colons). An asterisk (*) represents any combination of zero or more characters and a question mark (?) represents any single character. You can have use multiple * or ? characters in each segment, but a wildcard cannot span segments.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-arn-format.html

While this doesn't specifically say regular expressions are not supported, they are not mentioned, and both `*` and `?` have different meanings, entirely, within regular expressions, than what is allowed here... so they are ruled out by implication if nothing else.